# AudioTrack unknown entity error in my code

Tags: java, android, audiotrack

I try to generate 8bit sound in a java application on my Android phone, with the AIDE Google App, and I have trouble to create Audiotrack object, which is declared unknown entity, as an error in my code,coming from the following source :

https://progur.com/2016/12/how-to-create-8-bit-music-on-android.html

can you please help me? Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Please include the relevant information in the post.

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it, playing a little bit with The AIDE Google App editor, before its agreement on the AudioTrack object,
and enjoyed hearing 15s of 440Hz, after I run my app on my Android.